# PHP to Iterate through results and filter by dates

Tags: php

I am having json results as following

```
{
 "status": 200,
 "success": true,
 "data": [
   "Reports/2017/04/01/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/05/16/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/05/19/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/06/20/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/07/23/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/07/26/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/09/27/name.csv"
 ],
 "message": "Success"
}
```

These are my API results and i am having a type(weekly or monthly) variable. So when i pass my type value as monthly, my results should be

```
   "Reports/2017/04/01/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/05/19/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/06/20/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/07/26/name.csv",
   "Reports/2017/09/27/name.csv"
```

i want to have latest csv file for that month, i dont want to have all csv values in that month. Can anyone suggest me how to get this working??

Following is my code

```
   //comparing two dates and passing the dates for S3 bucket and i am saving all those values in array

     $begin = new DateTime("2017-01-17");
        $end = new DateTime("2017-09-28");
        $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');

        $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

        $date = "2017-01-17";
        $type = "month" // now my type is month, so i want to get the latest entry of csv file for each month

        $all_objs = array();
           foreach ( $period as $dt )
        {

             $res_objs = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(

                                                         "Bucket" => $bucket,

                                                         "Prefix" => 'Reports/'.$date.'/name.csv'

                                                   ));
    //$res_objs stores all the csv files from csv
            foreach ($res_objs as $obj) {
    // here i am saving in array
                  array_push($all_objs, $obj['Key']);

               }

               $date = date ("Y/m/d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));

           }
   // now, here i want to save those latest entries in a variable.
          return $all_objs;
```

Comment: What it means - `latest`?

Comment: yes i want to get the lastest csv file for every month

Comment: So iterate with a `foreach`, store lookup - month=>day

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: This is a little confusing, but from my understanding, you want the last report for a given month. In the case that your files are out of order, order your reports alphanumerically, and use a regex to parse the year and month values that you're passing to your function (something like `.*\/2017\/09\/.*`) where `2017` is the year you're passing (say variable `$year`) and `09` is the month you're passing (say variable `$month`) to get `".*\/{$year}\/{$month}\/.*"`. Then you can use `array_pop()` to get the last value in that array (which should be the last report that you're looking for)

Comment: i updated code in my question